# Pine Script: " Can't call 'security' inside: 'if', 'for' "

Tags: error-handling, pine-script

because I cant find any way to test my Pine Script strategy on multiple symbols, I created a way to loop through my whole Script.

In This I made 10 variables for 10 different Symbols like this:

```
ersteTicker = "AAPL"
zweiteTicker = "MSFT"
dritterTicker = "..."
```

Than I loopedfrom 1 to 10 and made 10 If-querys, which give me in every loop the right symbol like this:

```
a = 1
    for i = 0 to 10
        if a == 1
            tickerID = ersteTicker
        if a == 2
            tickerID = .....
```

Now I thougt everything should be all right, but now **the console gives back an error message called:**

**line 75: Can't call 'security' inside: 'if', 'for'**

Does anybody know how to bypass this problem??

best regards
Christian

P.S.: I already tested a small other script and in this script the console doesn't give me back this error message, even if I also made a for loop with a security function in it..

(looks like this)

```
//@version=3
strategy("Meine Strategie", overlay=true)
tickerID = "ADS"
vergleichstimeframe = "D"
TaesRSLPeriode = 200
a = 1

myEma() => ema(close, TaesRSLPeriode)
for i = 0 to 10 
    if ( a == 1)
        Daily_ema = security(tickerID, vergleichstimeframe, myEma())
        //plot(Daily_ema*TagesRSLGrenzwert)

        longCondition = crossover(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
        if (longCondition)
            strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)

        shortCondition = crossunder(sma(close, 14), sma(close, 28))
        if (shortCondition)
            strategy.entry("My Short Entry Id", strategy.short)
```

Comment: Why do you even need here security to be called inside of the loop/if? Have you tried put it outside the statements `for/if` and indide `for/if` just refer to the security's value?

Comment: Hello @Michel_T.,

I neet to use the security-function to get the specific Price of a specific Symbol and on a specific timeframe.

In My Code I use the Daily and the hourly Timeframe. This is why I need this security-function.

And if I want to get the price of different symbols (like f.e, AAPL, MSFT, GOOG,...) than I also need this function.

Or do you know a other way to get this data?

Comment: I don't mind using the secutiy, but why is it **inside** the `for`? Make the security global and the code will work.

Comment: In the for loop, there is my whole scipt. In This script I want to compare the hourly price and the daily price. So I need the security function in this for loop...
Or do you mean I should make a function outside the for loop and than just call the function in the for loop? Does this wok?

Comment: I've provided below some code as an example how'd I implement that feature.

Comment: @chrissi2909 Please don't post your question in multiple forums simultaneously. You risk getting different people volunteering their help in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of global security. The security must not be inside of neither for nor if statements. If you need more symbols - use more securities. But bear in mind, that you can't choose a symbol from a set of symbols and call security with that symbol (because it'll be mutable variable and you cannot use them with security):

```
//@version=3
strategy("Meine Strategie", overlay=true)
tickerID = "ADS"
vergleichstimeframe = "D"
TaesRSLPeriode = 200
a = 1

myEma() => ema(close, TaesRSLPeriode)

// this always must stay global 
Daily_ema = security(tickerID, vergleichstimeframe, myEma())
// here you could put more secureties:
//Daily_ema1 = security(tickerID1, vergleichstimeframe, myEma())
//Daily_ema2 = security(tickerID2, vergleichstimeframe, myEma())
//Daily_ema3 = security(tickerID3, vergleichstimeframe, myEma())
// ...

for i = 0 to 10 
    if a == 1
        if Daily_ema > Daily_ema[i] // actual using of the security's result
            strategy.entry("My Long Entry Id", strategy.long)
```

Comment: Thank you!! I will try this version!

Answer (score 0):

In general and according to previous comments, the strategy tester isn’t accurate. Just view an indication for the operation. Maybe the only benefit of the testing strategy is to determine the value of (SL, TP). Meanwhile the strategy depends on trusted intermittent periods, you can increase the SL 10 to avoid the temporary reflections